# Powerbi refresh report

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

We are publishing our powerbi reports embedded into a website with a PowerBI Premium Plan. All our analytic visualizations are on PowerBI but we are in troubles to offer some user interactions through the interface.

Specifically, we want to confirm some events pressing a button which is located on the same powerbi in order to call a backend API through a Javascript.

Fortunately, we've figured out how to solve this problem and our button is updating our database. But we couldn't solve the problem associated with limitations about numbers of requests to the power bi service. It is said that there is a limit of one request every 15 seconds. So, we have to wait 15 seconds to press the button again. Nobody will want to wait more than a few seconds to interact again with the button.

We've used the last example as is described in the following URL:
[Embedding Basic interactions](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Embedding---Basic-interactions#refresh-a-report)

Someone has experience with this kind of interactions on PowerBI? I find it a little strange, I do not find any information about this limitation on the Microsoft website

Here an example of the exception:

[image: Refresh exception]

Answer (score 1):

You are using PowerBI Embedded. This is a service from Microsoft where you pay for a certain amount of processing power. When you go over this processing power, PowerBI will return an error.

A capacity calculator is available to see how much processing power you would need. You can find it [on the Microsoft website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embedded-capacity-planning).

I'm not sure what you're using this functionality for. You say you use the button to "confirm some events" which suggests that the PowerBI solution is part of an interactive application. Do remember that PowerBI is an analytics platform and as such not really suited for real-time interaction. If this is the case I would strongly advise finding a different solution since higher-tier PowerBI embedded licenses are very expensive (and still won't guarantee that no error will be generated)